# PHP - Spawn workers for each new job in beanstalkd

Tags: php, jobs, beanstalkd

I am building this web application for server management. When a user creates a server this gets put onto a beanstalkd queue to be processed, this typically takes 1 to 2 minutes to complete.

However I want the job to be processed the moment it is dispatched. For example lets says there are two users who both build a server, obviously these two jobs would be put onto the queue to be processed. The first user would have to wait 1 - 2 minutes for the job to be processed, but the second user would have to wait 1 - 2 minutes for the first user's server to be built, then another 1 - 2 minutes for their server to be built. This essentially creates a sort of backlog, where a user would have to wait n + 1 minutes for their server to be built.

I want to avoid this from happening, so I was wondering if it was possible to spawn a new worker, or something similar, in beanstalkd to handle the new job the moment it is dispatched?

Answer (score 0):

For tasks that will take a while, but needed to be run concurrently, you would generally have a number of workers ready to go. Each would connect to the beanstalkd server, and wait for a job to become available. Should they be disconnect, they would simply reconnect (though I would pause a few seconds between attempts).

In order to run multiple copies, use of a tool such a as 'supervisord' is often used. This controls starting/restarting the workers.